# collection_start validates_presence_of conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails

models

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :deadline, :list_id, :name, :summary
  validates_presence_of :deadline, :list_id, :name, :summary

  belongs_to :list
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
end


<%= collection_select(:post, :list_id, List.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
```

Renders:

```
<select id="post_list_id" name="post[list_id]">
 <option value="">Please select</option>
 <option value="1">House</option>
 <option value="2">Car</option>
</select>
```

I set list_id to be required, when I select an list (list_id) from the drop-down when adding a task, it says the list_id was not selected. What could I be doing wrong?

[image]

UPDATE: figured it out, had to revise the collection_select line in the form view, I also did not include the f. part to it

```
f.collection_select(:list_id, List.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true})
```